# How to Set the value of the Cookies "Path" attribute to the actual virtual directory path of the application in Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, tomcat9

Here is my configuration in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>40</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer
[Absolute path in <mvc:resources/> instead of path relative to mapping of spring servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184066/absolute-path-in-mvcresources-instead-of-path-relative-to-mapping-of-spring)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/static/*">staticResources</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="staticResources" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/static/</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```